# How can I activate the current session in ConsoleKit?

Tags: consolekit, udisks

I have a live Debian Squeeze system on a USB drive, containing a script I use to image another drive. This script uses `udisks` to mount a drive by label, but it doesn't work over a serial console. The reason is that the session associated with the serial console does not appear to be "active", which means that `udisks` fails with:

```
user@my-live-usb:~$ udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-label/image-data --mount-options ro
Mount failed: Not Authorized
```

Changing the `allow_any` key in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks.policy` doesn't help, so I'd like to know how to tell ConsoleKit that the serial console is "active". Trying to do this via the DBUS interface fails:

```
user@my-live-usb:~$ dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session7 org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session.Activate
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.UnmappedError.CkSeatError.Code0: Unable to activate session
```

Session7 is the one listed as being on /dev/ttyS0.

So how can I get ConsoleKit to recognise the serial console as an active session?

(In my case, udisks version is 1.0.1+git20100614-3, consolekit is 0.4.1-4.)

It's also probably worth noting the the Debian live system automatically logs the live user in on all 6 video consoles and the serial console.

Answer (score 2):

The objective is to setup an active ConsoleKit session. You can check this via:

```
$ ck-list-sessions | grep active
    active = TRUE
```

If there are multiple ConsoleKit sessions only one session at most can be active at a time.

If the output is something like

```
$ ck-list-sessions | grep active
    active = FALSE
    active = FALSE
```

you have a problem because things that need an active ConsoleKit session to authenticate for sending messages over dbus do not work (e.g. NetworkManager, i.e. `nm-applet`, udisk ...).

There are several methods to create (and activate) a ConsoleKit session. The display manager may setup one via directly communicating with the ConsoleKit daemon. Or a pam-module may do it. Or a login/X11-session-init script might call ck-launch-session which should create an active session (modulo bugs).

Usually, the goal should be to setup ConsoleKit in such a way that you get an active session for your window manager or login shell (not just for single scripts).

To test the ConsoleKit system you can try to use `ck-launch-session` to create a proper consolekit session. For example you can call your script like this:

```
$ ck-launch-session ./script
```

To test if ck-launch-session is bug-free you can call

```
$ ck-launch-session ck-list-sessions
```

and check if there is an active session.

**Bugs:** Updates to the ConsoleKit system recently introduced [various](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=597937) [bugs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=657979) into the fragile (and over-engineered?) ConsoleKit ecosystem.

For example on my Ubuntu 11.10 system I had to delete `nox11` from the `pam_ck_connector.so` line in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` after `ck-launch-session` stopped working after a system upgrade:

```
--- a/pam.d/common-session      Fri May 25 10:26:53 2012 +0200
+++ b/pam.d/common-session      Fri May 25 10:39:41 2012 +0200
@@ -29,5 +29,5 @@
 session        required        pam_unix.so 
 session        optional                        pam_winbind.so 
 session        optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
-session        optional                        pam_ck_connector.so nox11
+session        optional                        pam_ck_connector.so
 # end of pam-auth-update config
```

With that change now I directly get an `active` session when starting my window manager via `WDM` login.

That means that the window manager now runs inside an active ConsoleKit session and everything that is started as a child from the window manager process (e.g. from an xterm) is also part of that session, i.e. no need for extra calls of `ck-launch-session` for e.g. `nm-applet` any more.

Comment: If I call `ck-launch-session bash` and run `ck-list-sessions` from within that terminal, the console still has `active = FALSE` for that session.

Comment: In fact, the easiest way to test this is to run `ck-launch-session bash -c 'pkexec true'`. If there's no output, it works. If you see (as I do) `Error executing command as another user: Not authorized`, it doesn't.

Comment: @detly, well, ConsoleKit really seems to be a fragile (and over-engineered?) piece of software. Depending on your method of starting X (via DM or not, which DM etc.) updates to the ConsoleKit system recently introduced [various](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=597937) [bugs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=657979).

Comment: @detly, updated the answer with a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with session, where `is-local` and `active` was `FALSE`.
`/bin/login` used `pam_ck_connector` to make a proper session.
Then I executed xinit with `ck-launch-session openbox` in `~/.xinitrc`.
The second session was broken.

The solution is NOT to use `ck-launch-session`,
but execute xinit staying on the same virtual terminal and keeping the existing first local session active: `XINITRC=/path_to_custom/xinitrc xinit -- :1 vt1`